# Zend Forms or simple html forms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

It is mandatory to use a Zend Form everytime I need one? Can I do it with a simple html form in my phtml?

Are there dangers or trouble using the html one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use pure html forms wherever you want.

Zend_Forms try to help to easily implement the best pratices particularly validating,  filtering and escaping user input. If you use pure HTML, you may forget these best pratices.